# R matrix: unique by one column, add the values on other column and concatenate the values on other

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

in R I have this matrix

```
> a
     id    size pattern                                 
[1,] "1"   "24"  "100"
[2,] "2"   "10"  "111"
[3,] "3"   "2"   "111"
```

and I want to unique by pattern, add the size and concatenate the id:

```
 > a
      id   size pattern                                 
 [1,] "1"    "24"  "100"
 [2,] "2-3"  "12"  "111" (this pattern was duplicated, so add size and concatenate id)
```

I can do:

```
> a = unique(a[,"pattern"])
```

but I couldn't figure out how to add and concatenate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some columns that you want to treat as numeric (adding the values together) and some that you want to treat as character (pasting them) then a matrix isn't the right structure for your data. You should be using a data frame.

Using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data.frame(a), .(pattern), summarise, 
      id=paste(id, collapse="-"),
      size=sum(as.numeric(size)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but i'm having an error: \\
Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: `sep` in the `paste` call should be `collapse`. Try it again.